# Merge two columns into one, delete colnames

Tags: r, merge

I have a table like:

```
a
 n_msi2010 n_msi2011
1 -0.122876  1.818750
2  1.328930  0.931426
3 -0.111653  4.400060
4  1.222900  4.500450
5  3.604160  6.110930
```

I would like to **merge these two columns into one column** to obtain (I don't want to keep column names):

```
a
  n_msi2010 
1 -0.122876  
2  1.328930  
3 -0.111653  
4  1.222900  
5  3.604160  
6  1.818750
7  0.931426
8  4.400060
9  4.500450
10 6.110930
```

When I am using prefabricated data like

```
x <- cbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6))
colnames(x)<-c("a","b")
c(t(x))
# 1 4 2 5 3 6
c((x))
# 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

the column merging works fine. Only in "a" exemple id doesn't work and it creates 2 separate vectors. I don't really understand why. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Could your "table" be a data.frame? Your `x` is a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your question is about column versus row order vector creation from a `data.frame`.

Using `t()` on a `data.frame` converts the `data.frame` to a `matrix`, and using `c()` on the `matrix` removes its dimensions.

With that knowledge, you can try:

```
# create a vector of values, column by column
c(as.matrix(a))  # you are missing the `as.matrix` in your current approach

# create a vector of values, row by row
c(t(a))          # you already know this works
```

Other approaches to get the "column by column" result would be:

```
unlist(a, use.names = FALSE)
stack(a)[, "values"]     # add `drop = FALSE` if you want to retain a data.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a elegant way but it seems it can combine two or several columns to one.

```
n_msi2010 <- 1:5
n_msi2011 <- 6:10
a <- data.frame(n_msi2010, n_msi2011)

vector <- vector()

for (i in 1:dim(a)[2]){
    vector <- append(vector, as.vector(a[,i]))
    vector  
}
```

You may do

```
as.matrix(vector) or data.frame(vector)
```